Book where a parent recounts an anecdote about a painting of a Russian sled pursued by wolves
I was recently reading a story (a piece of Worm fanfiction) where a character cited a "Russian proverb" about a sled being pursued by wolves where they had to decide who would be thrown to the wolves to distract them and it brought back memories of a book I read in my childhood (probably 1990s in Kentucky) where a family is doing a road trip, with various amusing incidents happening, and the father of the family at one point recounting having seen a painting with said troika (and I'm fairly certain that term was cited) and the ambiguity of that a baby was shown either falling or being thrown to the wolves, and him at one point stating that he was starting to understand the painting.
Other things I recall from the story:

There were at least one boy and one girl, who I don't think were related to each other, in the traveling group.
There was a scene where the kids got ahold of some paint, including the color turquoise, and touched up some paintings they grabbed second hand — I remember them taking a scene of mountains and adding an egg at the peak of a mountain, and a spider moving up toward it — and somehow parlaying that into selling the paintings for a higher price as the work of an unknown artist
A scene where the boy got a nosebleed, and had to send the girl for help, and it later being recounted breathlessly by another traveler as a young boy seen by the stream, bleeding to death, whose body was nowhere to be found when they came back with help.
A scene where the boy and girl had to strip down, I think to dye their skin — I don't remember the context — which was depicted in a line-and-ink style in the illustration. The picture was done in a way that avoided most prurient detail, although I think the boy's buttocks were visible, and either they were too young to think it scandalous, or they were too friendly to think anything of it.

I fairly vividly remember the nosebleed incident because I was very prone to them as a child, and indeed remember my mother having to try to clean blood off of a page (maybe the same book) after I'd spontaneously started bleeding on it.

This sounds very much like Henry Reed's Journey by Keith Robertson, first published in 1973.
The titular Henry Reed is a teenage boy, and the son of a diplomat. The book tells the story of a car-trip he took from San Francisco to New Jersey with the Glass family. The family have a daughter, Midge, and she and Henry get up to a few adventures along the way.
The description of the "throwing the baby to the wolves" comes about halfway through the book, when Mr Glass is complaining about the car being overcrowded:

Sooner or later we are going to have to start throwing people
overboard," Mr. Glass said. "Have you two children ever seen that
painting of the Russians in a sleigh being chased across the
snow-covered steppes by wolves?"

The anecdote about doctoring the picture occurs when the children enter a painting competition in Taos, New Mexico. They take a dull picture of a landscape hanging in their hotel room, and doctor it by adding first some vegetables (an eggplant and a carrot), and then an egg, and not one, but two spiders:

I painted the egg, and I have to admit the painting did look more
interesting than it had before. It certainly had more color. I hadn't
used any of the turquoise, and I was trying to think of something that
color when a spider ran across the floor. I'd never seen a turquoise
spider, but then I'd never seen an egg balanced on a mountain peak. I
painted two spiders climbing up toward the egg and showed the results
to Midge.

The scene where the boy and girl strip down to dye their skin happens when they help out at a carnival parade. The local Hopi Indians had a float in the parade, but as the chief's daughter fell ill the children offered to take her place. To change their skin tone from "paleface to redskin" (this part of the book has not aged well), they rubbed themselves with a fluid made from treebark.

I don't see any reference to the nosebleed incident though. Possibly it happened in another Henry Reed... book, or I've missed it somehow.
The full book is available for free loan from the Internet Archive.

Ah! And it's apparently Henry Reed's Big Show with the nosebleed.

Very interesting! This book may be the inspiration for one (in)famous Dutch poem / pop song which was published a year later, even though the Wikipedia page says sacrificing travel companions wasn't unheard of in 19th century Russia.
